# What are the requirements for the different endings in Metroid?

Tags: metroid

What are the requirements for each different ending in Metroid and what are the differences between each of them?

Comment: Ingame command prompt == `virtual-console` != emulator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 5 different endings. You can see screenshots of all of them along with requirements here: http://www.vgmuseum.com/end/nes/b/met.htm

- Under 1 hour: Samus removes her suit, revealing a bikini
- 1-3 hours: Samus removes her suit, revealing a one-piece swimsuit
- 3-5 hours: Samus removes only her helmet
- 5-10 hours: Samus waves, but leaves her suit on
- 10+ hours: Samus turns her head away in shame

[The Metroid Database](http://metroid-database.com/m1/endings.php) lists slightly different requirements for the two worst endings:

- 5+ hours, played with normal Samus: Samus Waves, but leaves her suit on
- 5+ hours, played with suitless-Samus: Samus turns her head away in shame

I'm not sure which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one other ending that may be tied in with the "JUSTIN BAILEY _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _" code in which Samus has smoke coming from her gun and -don't quote me on this one- the same ending may be available for completing the game with some of the other unusual codes.